# JPA Bind Parameter in Literal Value

Tags: oracle, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I need to use Oracle `JSON_TRANSFORM` function in my Spring Boot app to update a single field in my complex JSON which containing huge amount of JSON fields and arrays. Here's a snippet of the native query implementation,

```
interface MyRepository extends JpaRepository<MyEntity, Integer> {
   @Query(value = """
   UPDATE my_table
   SET my_table, JSON_TRANSFORM(
      my_table.json_column,
      REPLACE '$.my_list[*]?(@..id == "4U52wZZ4snpQMAnt8gOYT").name' = :name
   )
   """, nativeQuery = true
   )
   @Modifying
   public update(@Param("id") String id, @Param("name") String name);
}
```

This code working just fine. But one more thing to finalize the implementation is I need to make the predicate parameterized. How can I achieve that?

---

Updating this question, I found that Oracle support `PASSING` clause that can binds SQL values to SQL/JSON variables for use in path expressions. Reference: [PASSING Clause for SQL Functions and Conditions](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/23/adjsn/clauses-used-in-functions-and-conditions-for-json.html#GUID-B86088D2-9CBF-4F73-B510-9EBC2471365A).

Adding my constraint into the question, I'm using Oracle 19c, I found that the document for this version in [Oracle SQL Function JSON_TRANSFORM](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/adjsn/oracle-sql-function-json_transform.html#GUID-7BED994B-EAA3-4FF0-824D-C12ADAB862C1) also mentioning

> Following the sequence of modification operations that you specify, you can include optional RETURNING and PASSING clauses

But when I try it I'm having error `ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis` as the query shown below,

```
UPDATE my_table
SET json_column, JSON_TRANSFORM(
   my_table.json_column,
   REPLACE '$.my_list[*]?(@..id == $id).name'
   PASSING '4U52wZZ4snpQMAnt8gOYT' AS "id" = :name
)
```

As comparison, the `PASSING` clause works on `JSON_EXISTS` function as the sample query shown below,

```
SELECT * FROM my_table
WHERE JSON_EXISTS(
   my_table.json_column,
   '$.my_list[*]?(@..id == $id)'
   PASSING '4U52wZZ4snpQMAnt8gOYT' AS "id"
);
```

After done some research online, I found some answer in the forum that `PASSING` clause doesn't work for `JSON_TRANSFORM` function. One of them is [How to use json_transform to remove an array element at an unknown index?](https://forums.oracle.com/ords/apexds/post/how-to-use-json-transform-to-remove-an-array-element-at-an-0193).

So is that true? if so then Oracle document is misleading and might need to be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I found that Oracle support `PASSING` clause that can binds SQL values to SQL/JSON variables for use in path expressions. Reference: [PASSING Clause for SQL Functions and Conditions](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/23/adjsn/clauses-used-in-functions-and-conditions-for-json.html#GUID-B86088D2-9CBF-4F73-B510-9EBC2471365A). But so far I'm seeing that this feature available starting from **Oracle 23c**.